# How to load assets with asset manager on Android?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to load a skin from the asset manager:

```
public Assets() {
    manager = new AssetManager();

    manager.load("bin/fonts/loading.json", Skin.class);
    manager.finishLoading();
    loadingSkin = manager.get("bin/fonts/loading.json", Skin.class);
}
```

This works on desktop, but on Android the asset manager can't load the JSON, and it throws an exception.

Comment: You should not have a "bin/" at the start of your path, unless you actually have a bin directory within the assets directory.

Comment: @nEx.Software I dont, but I need it to load assets on desktop, for whatever reason. It doesnt work like that on android though.

Comment: You'll want to set the working directory to the assets directory in the desktop run configuration so you don't have to add the "bin/" to your paths.

Comment: Also I presume this code is only for demonstration? Because the way you implemented assetmanager it's kinda useless. If this is your actual code, look here for some more tips on how to use it properly: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: @p.streef this is just so the skin is loaded before loading the rest of the textures. is doing it this way inefficient?

Comment: The assetmanager loads items in order you add them, so if you add the skin first it will always be loaded first. I recommend using a custom splash/loading screen in which you use the assetManager.update() method until it finishes loading.

Comment: @p.streef oops, forgot to say, the skin is actually used for the splash screen, I need it immediately before loading the rest so I use finishLoading(), sorry, was a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the working directory to the assets directory in the android run configuration.